# Crear usuario Administrador mediante una vista

Tags: python, django, poo

Actualmente estoy tomando un proyecto que esta muy avanzado y adicionalmente soy nuevo en django .

Quisiera Saber de que manera puedo añadir a un usuario como administrador desde view ,normalmente los desarrolladores quienes iniciaron el proyecto  lo realizaban desde el shell de python mostrare de que manera ellos lo realizaban y que adelanto tengo en la view pero no me agrega el usuario en el modelo de administrador:

## Desde el Shell asi se crean los usuario administrador:##

```
def load_examples(apps, schema_editor):

user = PlazasUser.objects.get(id=0)
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(PlazasUser)
permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='admin',
                                   name='Administrator',
                                   content_type=content_type)
user.user_permissions.add(permission)
user.is_active = True
user.save()
```

> De esta manera se crean los usuario administradores desde el shell ahora bien esto quiero llevarlo a una vista pero no me registra el usuariio como administrador:

### Models:

```
class PlazasUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

sap_id = models.CharField('Número de SAP', max_length=20)

id = models.CharField('Identificador', max_length=10, primary_key=True, unique=True, null=False)

id_type = models.CharField('Tipo de documento', max_length=1,
                           choices=(('V', 'Venezolano'), ('E', 'Extranjero'), ('J', 'Jurídico')))
email = models.EmailField('Correo electrónico', max_length=255, unique=True)
name = models.CharField('Nombre', max_length=30, null=False)
last_name = models.CharField('Apellido', max_length=30, null=False)
failed_login = models.SmallIntegerField('Intentos fallidos', default=0)
needs_sap_modify = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField('Está activo', default=False)
want_mails = models.BooleanField('Desea reciibir correos de Automercados Plaza\'s', default=False)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

 Class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(PlazasUser, primary_key=True)
phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\d{4}-\d{7}$',
                             message="El número telefónico debe tener el formato: '0212-1112233'")

phone_number = models.CharField('Número telefónico', max_length=12, validators=[phone_regex])
mobile_number = models.CharField('Teléfono móvil', max_length=12, validators=[phone_regex])
birthday = models.DateField()
is_suma = models.BooleanField('Es cliente suma', default=False)
is_sap = models.BooleanField('Es cliente SAP', default=False)
want_mails = models.BooleanField('Desea reciibir correos de Automercados Plaza\'s', default=False)

objects = CustomerManager()

def __str__(self):
    return'{}'.format(self.user)
```

> Ahora bien estoy desarrollado la siguiente view y template pero no me agrega el usuario como admin:

### VIEW:

```
def admincreate(request):
   if request.method=='POST':
    form=UserContentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form = Customer.objects.get()
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Customer)
        permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='admin',name='Administrator',content_type=content_type)
        form.user_permissions.add(permission)
        form.is_active = True
        form.save()
    return redirect('admin')
else:
    form=UserContentForm()
return render(request,'admin_create_user_cont.html',{'form':form})
```

### Template:

```
 <form method="POST" ">
          <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
          <br>
          <h3>Usuario:</h3>


          <div class="col-md-10"> 
                  <center>     {{form.user}}        </center>



         </div>
```

### Formularios:

```
class UserContentForm(forms.ModelForm): 
   class Meta:

    model=Customer

    fields=[
        'user',

    ]   

    labels={
        'user':'user',

          }
    widgets={

        'user':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),

    }
```

Comment: Cual es el problema? No veo ningún error... Qué está ocurriendo con tu código actual y que esperas que ocurra?

Comment: Hola amigo,este es un proyecto que esta muy adelantado por otros desarrolladores y yo tengo poco conocimiento en django. Normalmente los desarroladores registraban usuario Admin desde el shell como lo muestroen  el codigo  de arriba .estructure una vista ,formulario y template que registre el usuario mediante la vista pero al darle el boton submit me redirecciona `return redirect('admin')` pero cuando voy a la bases de datos no me agrega al usuario seleccionado como admin. siento que el error esta en la vista porque en el .get no asigno el cliente por el usuario.

Comment: Considero que el error esta aqui ` form = Customer.objects.get()`  por no selerecciono el request que fue introducido por el usuario en el formulario,pero no se como hacer para que el request sea seleccionado por el usuario y no sea manual por ejemplo asi `user = PlazasUser.objects.get(nombre='jesus')`

Comment: Mmmmm, sigo sin comprenderte mucho, pues me parece que intentas hacer cosas que django ya hace por si solo... Sin embargo en tu vista, antes de entrar al redirect, estas preguntando si el formulario es valido, ponle un else asi: `else: print(form.errors)` y mira que error tira el formulario, yo diria que el html que tienes el formulario no estas enviando nada...

Comment: Me da este error  `<ul class="errorlist"><li>user<ul class="errorlist"><li>Customer con esta User ya existe.</li></ul></li></ul> `   se que ya existe en customer pero quiero agregarles los permisos a X usuario

Comment: me ha dado este error adicionalmente  
`get() returned more than one PlazasUser -- it returned 24!`

Comment: Para el segundo error la linea del error es esta `form = Customer.objects.get()`, pero sinceramente, te recomiendo leas la documentación de django. Pues obviamente no estas haciendo bien al agregarle los permisos al objeto `Customer` y no al objeto `User`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

desde la terminal `python manage.py shell`

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> u = User.objects.get(username='john')
>>> u.is_superuser = True
>>> u.save()
```

o con este comando desde la terminal [`django-admin createsuperuser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser)

Si quieres una ruta para que cualquiera pueda modificar desde la web podrías realizar algo así:

```
def newSuperUser(request, id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        is_superuser = request.POST.get('isSuperuser') #name del input en HTML
        user.is_superuser = is_superuser
        user.save()
```

la variable is_superuser obtiene el dato del input type="checkbox"

Comment: como hago para que el get  haga la seleccion de registro de datos mediante un post y que no sea de esta manera manual `u = User.objects.get(username='john')`

Comment: modifique la respuesta y la segunda parte creo que es lo que necesitas @jpozzo

Answer (score 0):

Listo de todas maneras gracias por su Ayuda para poder Agregar el roll de usuario administrado solo tenia que cambiar esta linea de codigo

```
permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='admin',name='Administrator',content_type=content_type)
```

por:

```
permission = Permission.objects.get(codename='admin',name='Administrator',content_type=content_type)
```